# SQL: Selecting between date range

Tags: sql, ms-access

My query returns 1 value if I use the Max(SampleDateTime) or Min( ) on the Date/Time field I want, but it returns no values if I leave out the Max or Min.  I want to return ALL the values, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I want all the Quality Samples between the Start and Stop times of a Production Run.

RunSamples:

```
Select Max([SampleDateTime]) 
FROM [QualitySamples] AS [GoodSamples] 
WHERE [GoodSamples].[SampleDateTime] >= [ProductionRuns_tbl].[RunStartDate] 
    AND [GoodSamples].[SampleDateTime] <= [ProductionRuns_tbl].[RunEndDate]
```

ProductionRuns_tbl:
RunStartDate         RunEndDate
1/1/2017 12 AM   1/5/17 12 AM
...

QualitySamples Tbl:
    ID SampleDateTime
    1  1/1/2017 2 am
    2  1/1/2017 3 am
...

Here's the full SQL code:

```
SELECT ProductionRuns_tbl.RunName, ProductionRuns_tbl.RunStartDate, 
ProductionRuns_tbl.RunEndDate,
 (Select Max([SampleDateTime]) 
 FROM [QualitySamples] AS [GoodSamples] 
 WHERE [GoodSamples].[SampleDateTime] >= [ProductionRuns_tbl].[RunStartDate] 
 AND [GoodSamples].[SampleDateTime] <= [ProductionRuns_tbl].[RunEndDate])
AS RunSamples
FROM ProductionRuns_tbl
WHERE (((ProductionRuns_tbl.RunName)=[Forms]![Home]![RunName]));
```

Comment: Please show us your data.  Do you have actual data between those two dates, RunStartDate and RunEndDate ?

Comment: you are using MAX so you'll get only one value.

Comment: Right - if I remove the MAX I get no values from the query

Comment: I've tried using Min and Max, and both work Joe - I definitely get the Min and Max values in teh Sample data set, so I know I have data between these dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a risk posting right now, because I had to try to read your mind on what you're trying to do  (plus, I don't know if this will work in Access, but it will work in SQL server)

Since you want all the data, is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT 
    ProductionRuns_tbl.RunName, 
    ProductionRuns_tbl.RunStartDate, 
    ProductionRuns_tbl.RunEndDate,
    [QualitySamples].[SampleDateTime]
FROM
    ProductionRuns_tbl
LEFT JOIN
    [QualitySamples]
ON
    [QualitySamples].[SampleDateTime] >= [ProductionRuns_tbl].[RunStartDate] 
    AND
    [QualitySamples].[SampleDateTime] <= [ProductionRuns_tbl].[RunEndDate]
WHERE 
    (((ProductionRuns_tbl.RunName)=[Forms]![Home]![RunName]));
```

This should list the RunName, Start and End dates repeated for each individual SampleDateTime.   Based on your more specific requirements, you can then refine the results from there.

Comment: Thanks Joe for all the help - works like a charm.  Needed the Left Join

Comment: @shwan - Glad to help.  Please read up on the differences between `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`.  You can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Answer (score 1):

Try to use join instead:

```
SELECT ProductionRuns_tbl.RunName,
       ProductionRuns_tbl.RunStartDate, 
       ProductionRuns_tbl.RunEndDate,
        GoodSamples.SampleDateTime
FROM QualitySamples GoodSamples INNER JOIN ProductionRuns_tbl ON 
    GoodSamples.SampleDateTime >= ProductionRuns_tbl.RunStartDate AND 
    GoodSamples.SampleDateTime <= ProductionRuns_tbl.RunEndDate
WHERE ProductionRuns_tbl.RunName=[Forms]![Home]![RunName]
```

Comment: Thanks Robert - the key was the inner join!

Answer (score 0):

Dont have **WHERE**, **MAX** or **MIN**. Just have the **SELECT** query.

```
Select [SampleDateTime]
FROM [QualitySamples] AS [GoodSamples]
```

Comment: Hmm...this says "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Comment: @shwan  OH... is this supposed to be a subquery within a bigger query ?